# How can I specify and output folder separately from the output file in C?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, console, fopen

So my program runs from a command line and automates some assembly language from an input. I wanna try and keep the arguments to a certain format which goes as follows: Argument 1 is an input file, argument 2 is the output filename, and argument 3 is the output file path (not required).

I'm not sure if I can directly use `fopen(),` since the input appears to require a location, and I don't wanna just mash strings together like `sprintf(File, "%s%s.asm", Path, name)`
since that can pose the risk of outputting something like `"~/DesktopDanceMusic.asm"` as opposed to `"~/Desktop/DanceMusic.asm"`, and I wanna make it a little forgiving.

The reason I don't just have the user specify the name in the path is because the filename is also referenced in the file.

For example if I gave a name like "DanceMusic" it would output the file `DanceMusic.asm` and inside contain headers like `DanceMusic_Instruments`

Because of that, the file can't contain an extension in the string and it has to be apart from the path. I'm going to have it add the extension on it's own.

Is there anything out there so I'm not reinventing the wheel? Maybe something about `fopen()` I don't know about? Or is this something I'll have to handle from scratch. Sadly the depths of google and duck duck go were no help to me.

Comment: Using sprintf the way you do is often how I construct paths. You just need to put a path separator between the path and file format specifiers.

Comment: Why are you making `sprintf()` process the third `%s` if you know it will be ".asm"... Sometimes you have to roll up your sleeves and write code. No, there's no _magic_ in `fopen()` that accounts for the whims of particular needs.

Comment: Oof. You're right. I wrote it in a rush. I'll fix that real quick. I wasn't really looking for a magic solution, but I thought I was missing something.